# Difference between BASH Scripting and AWK

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

What is the difference between BASH Scripting and AWK?

When would I use one over the other?

Comment: ?? awk is a shell command. you can't use it without the shell

Comment: @andrew - awk is an executable.  You can call it from a program without invoking a shell.  For people getting started with writing shell scripts, it can be confusing where the shell built-ins 'end.'

Comment: @shekharsuman You're mistaken.  This gist is an strace as evidence.  Note that the shell isn't invoked as a result of calling awk: https://gist.github.com/tristanfisher/e88f2c2a0cacf0ee5a81

Comment: A shell is simply an environment from which to call tools, with an associated programming language to let you sequence those calls. Awk is the standard UNIX tool to process text files.

Answer (score 5):

I think that from `bash Scripting` you are referring to general scripting that performs everything.

But,awk is basically an independent tool which can be called independently,even without invoking the bash shell(or any shell)!It is an independent tool as mentioned by `tristan`!

`bash Scripting` is used for performing any kind of operations using the shell!In fact,what you can achieve through `awk` can be achieved directly in bash scripts using other filters or even grep regex.And in addition,you can perform many other things which is not achievable through `awk`!

`awk` is an excellent filter and report writer.Many UNIX utilities generates rows and columns of information. AWK is an excellent tool for processing these rows and columns, and is easier to use AWK than most conventional programming languages. It can be considered to be a pseudo-C interpretor, as it understands the same arithmatic operators as C. AWK also has string manipulation functions, so it can search for particular strings and modify the output. AWK also has associative arrays, which are incredible useful, and is a feature most computing languages lack.

Comment: Source of last paragraph in above answer: https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~br/courses/cs699-autumn2013/refs/awk-tutorial-bruce-barnett.html.

Comment: link down.......

Answer (score 5):

Awk is just another tool that you can call easily from a Bash script.

You would call awk when you need to filter data and a built-in function to Bash doesn't (or doesn't easily) do what you need.  You can use Bash to define your logical flow and tools like `sed` or `awk` to manipulate data or do work.  Awk is good at filtering data from files.

For what it's worth, I've never heard of someone considering a script to not be a "bash script" because it invokes Awk.